# OnCreateOptionsMenu not called when Style set to a Dialog Theme

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have an activity in Android.  Specifically, I am using Xamarin.Android, formerly monodroid.  I have an activity.  When it is running on a phone (small screen device), we want the activity to be full screen.  When it runs on a tablet, we want the activity to have a "border" around similar to a dialog.  I do a programmatic check to get the screen dimensions and then determine if we are on a tablet or phone.  If we are on a phone, I call an activity's SetTheme method and pass in a dialog theme.  I have tried several dialog themes with no difference.  My menu items do not show.  I track this down and my overridden OnCreateOptionsMenu method is not called.  I know because I set a breakpoint in the first line of my activty's OnCreateOptionsMenu method and the breakpoint is not hit.

The code that I am using to set the theme is:
this.SetTheme (Android.Resource.Style.ThemeDialog);
I've also tried this from the Activty's theme attributes, but I am getting the same result.

I'm looking for any ideas, thoughts, whatever.

Thanks for your time.
Wally

Comment: I have a repo - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4149249/DialogExample.zip
I finally figured out the sequence of the problem.  If I set the theme before I load the content to view, then I get the theme, but no items in my options menu.  If I load the theme second, I get the content to view and the menu items, but no theme.  Any ideas from anyone are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By default the dialog theme does not have an actionbar. No reason to create menu items without it (on newer android versions).

Call `RequestWindowFeature (WindowFeatures.ActionBar);` in `onCreate` to get an actionbar in a dialog themed activity. Then `OnCreateOptionsMenu` will be called